# How to load Angular GET request response data into different lists?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I want to build a frontend application that consume my REST API (built with Django).
I have searched since two days but I cannot get a satisfying answer to my question. I tried to ask Chat GPT but it seems like it's always busy (can't access after I logged in).
I have created a services and models to make everything comfortable but it doesn't work.

I trying to load API data into several lists in my HomeComponent.

**Here is my model:**

```
export interface ProductList{
  total_pages: number;
  current_page: number;
  has_next: boolean;
  has_prev: boolean;
  page_items_count: number;
  items_per_page: number;
  data: [
    id: number,
    name: string,
    picture: string,
    price: number,
    discount: number | null,
    saved_amount: number,
    discount_percent: number | null,
    slug: string,
    is_available: boolean,
    ratings_average: number,
    ratings_count: number,
    date: string,
    uuid: string,
    extra_data: any,
    category: Category,
  ]
}

export interface ProductDetail{} // For now, I haven't designed ProductDetail model. Just declared it.
```

**My Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, catchError, of, map } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductList, ProductDetail } from '../../models/products.models';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
  baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: Error, errorValue: any) {
    return of(errorValue);
  }



  getProductList(): Observable<ProductList[]> {
    const productUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/`
    return this.http.get<ProductList[]>(productUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }


  getProductDetail(product_id: number): Observable<ProductDetail|undefined> {
    const productDetaiLlUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/${product_id}/`
    return this.http.get<ProductDetail>(productDetaiLlUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, undefined))
    );
  }


  getUnavailableProductList(): Observable<ProductList[]> {
    const productUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/unvailable/`
    return this.http.get<ProductList[]>(productUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }


  searchProducts(query: string|null): Observable<ProductList[]> {
    const params = query ? new HttpParams().set('q', query): {}
    const searchUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/search/`
    return this.http.get<ProductList[]>(searchUrl, { params: params, headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }

}
```

**My HomeComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductList } from '../../models/products.models';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products/products.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  public productList: ProductList[];
  products = [];
  public total_pages: number;
  public current_page: number;
  public has_next: boolean;
  public has_prev: boolean;
  public page_items_count: number;
  public items_per_page: number;
  public _products = []

  constructor (private productService: ProductsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProductList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.productList = res; 
      // Here, I want to load values of the key "data" (a list of products) into this.productList
      // And also the value of key "total_pages" in this.total_pages and so on (for the rest of the other variables that I declared.
    });
  }
}
```

Well, when I send the GET request, I'm receiving correct data but I can't loop through that data.
If I do `*ngFor="let product of productList.data"` it shows an error. For some reason, I want to access all of these data separately.

With `console.log(this.productList)`, the entire response is loaded but I only want to access products from key "productList.data" and display them. But the problem is that I can't load data separately and can't also loop through "productList.data" to get products.

Below is the schema of response when I send a GET request to products (the key "data" is a list of products)
[Response schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF0eA.png)

**So how can I get those data, load them in different lists and send them to my HTML view ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

When I send a request to my backend, it doesn't return a list of products but an object containing a list of products (with `data` key: `"data": []`
So instead of tell to ProductService to return a list of products, I changed into an object. And this object contains a list of products like I said.

So here are my new models: **products.models.ts**

```
export interface Product{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  picture: string;
  price: number;
  discount: number | null;
  saved_amount: number;
  discount_percent: number | null;
  slug: string;
  is_available: boolean;
  date: string;
  ratings_average: number;
  ratings_count: number;
  uuid: string;
  extra_data: any;
  category: Category;
}

export interface ProductObject{
  total_pages: number;
  current_page: number;
  has_next: boolean;
  has_prev: boolean;
  page_items_count: number;
  items_per_page: number;
  data: Product[]; // products are available here in "data" key
}
```

My new **products.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, catchError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductObject, ProductDetailObject } from '../../models/products.models';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {
  baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api";
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: Error, errorValue: any) {
    return of(errorValue);
  }



  getProductList(): Observable<ProductObject> {
    const productUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/`
    return this.http.get<ProductObject>(productUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }


  getProductDetail(product_id: number): Observable<ProductDetailObject|undefined> {
    const productDetaiLlUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/${product_id}/`
    return this.http.get<ProductDetailObject>(productDetaiLlUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, undefined))
    );
  }


  getUnavailableProductList(): Observable<ProductObject> {
    const productUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/unvailable/`
    return this.http.get<ProductObject>(productUrl, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }


  searchProducts(query: string|null): Observable<ProductObject> {
    const params = query ? new HttpParams().set('q', query): {}
    const searchUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/products/search/`
    return this.http.get<ProductObject>(searchUrl, { params: params, headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => this.handleError(error, []))
    );
  }

}
```

As you can see, I'm returning now an object of my API response.

So I found the correct/perfect way to answer my question (**How to load Angular GET request response data into different lists?**)

*I can now restructure data that I got from my service and load data into different variables.*

So here is how my **homepage.component.ts** looks now:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductObject, Product } from '../../models/products.models';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/app/services/products/products.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor (private productService: ProductsService) {}

  // PRODUCTS vars
  productObject: ProductObject;
  products: Product[];
  productsTotalPages: number;
  productsCurrentPage: number;
  productsHasNext: boolean;
  productsHasPrev: boolean;
  productsPageItemsCount: number;
  productsItemsPerPage: number;


  ngOnInit() {
    // GET products data
    this.productService.getProductList().subscribe((productsData) => {
      this.productObject = productsData;

      this.products = productsData.data;
      this.productsTotalPages = productsData.total_pages;
      this.productsCurrentPage = productsData.current_page;
      this.productsHasNext = productsData.has_next;
      this.productsHasPrev = productsData.has_prev;
      this.productsPageItemsCount = productsData.page_items_count;
      this.productsItemsPerPage = productsData.items_per_page;
    });
  }
}
```

I can now iterate over my `products` in my HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

The data type for `data` within the `ProductList` interface is wrong, if `data` is supposed to be an array, you define it like this in Typescript:

```js
export interface ProductList { 
  ...
  ...
  data: MyData[]; // MyData is the data type for data property
} 

export interface MyData {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  picture: string,
  price: number,
  discount: number | null,
  saved_amount: number,
  discount_percent: number | null,
  slug: string,
  is_available: boolean,
  ratings_average: number,
  ratings_count: number,
  date: string,
  uuid: string,
  extra_data: any,
  category: Category
}
```

Additionally, your `productList` class property is an array given your definition `public productList: ProductList[];`, so in order to get access of an individual `data`, you'll need to iterate twice with `ngFor`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <div *ngFor="let myData of product.data">
    <p>{{ myData.discount }}</p>
    <p>{{ myData.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ myData.uuid }}</p>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```